# Problem with upgrade to Nativescript 5.1.1

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I'm facing an issue with tns versions.

I'm running **tns --version** in both terminals.

Visual Studio Code terminal output **tns version: 5.0.0**

In Mac terminal **tns version: 5.1.1**

Any ideas how can I update Visual studio code to use latest version?

I'm tried to run in visual studio code terminal

npm install -g nativescript, and gone through the whole recommended update process in Nativescript documentation.

Nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `which tns` in terminal and in visual code's terminal to see the full path to the nativescript.

Also you can restart terminal and visual code to see if the problem will be resolved.

Comment: Okay, I've checked and they are different. How to fix the differences? And why they are happening?

Comment: Thanks your command helped me! After spotting the differences I've run the command "printenv" and saw the different environmental variable paths. So I went through the path of the wrong version tns (in my case Visual studio code) and deleted the tns shortcut from there. This solved the issue.